# Issues rendering static files on Pythonanywhere

Tags: flask, pythonanywhere

I am trying to host a Flask application using Pythonanywhere and I am having issues with rendering an image. I am pretty sure I have navigated to it correctly but it still fails to find and display it.

The Code for my webpage is here:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}


{% block content %}

<div class="media">
  <div class="media-left media-top">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="media-object" height = "130" width = "130"       src="/home/jamesk93/mysite/app/static/images/profilepic.jpg" alt="">
</a>
  </div>

 <div class="media-body">
    <h3 class="media-heading"></h3>
    <p>University Attended: </p>
    <p> </p>
    <p> </p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
  </div>
</div>


{% endblock %}
```

My application looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home')
def homepage():
    return render_template("home.html")


@app.route('/education')
def education():
    return render_template("education.html")

@app.route('/employment')
def employment():
    return render_template("employment.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I have done a little bit of research and I think its because I need to serve my static folder but I'm not really sure how to go about that so thats why Im asking on here (if thats even the problem)

Answer (score 3):

On the Web tab in Pythonanywhere, you can find a Static files section.

Add a URL and directory there.

On my application, I have two defined as shown below:

```
URL              Directory
/static/         /home/user/project/app/static/
/uploads/        /home/user/project/app/uploads/
```

More details can be found in the Pythonanywhere help document: 
https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/StaticFiles